# Body background images not shown on iPad and iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, html, css, ipad

I have created a website which works well on the desktop, but on iPhone and iPad background images are not shown.

I have tried deleting the php script that chooses the image and re-written the code to use javascript to set the background and in this case the background is showed correctly.

This is the php code that chooses the image:

```
<?php
//if  doesn't exist, open the session
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_start();
}
//set coockie
setcookie("allweb","connected", time()+3600);
//if doesn' exist yet, I create a new array
if(!isset($_SESSION['arrayImage'])){
    $arrayImage = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);
}else{// else I get from sessiom
    $arrayImage = $_SESSION['arrayImage'];  
}
//if already exist variable $picture, increment it
if(isset($_SESSION['picture']) && isset($arrayImage)){
    $picture=$_SESSION['picture'];
    $picture = $picture + 1;
    $_SESSION['picture'] = $picture;//save picture
}else{// else I create it
    $picture = 1;
    $_SESSION['picture'] = $picture;// save it
    shuffle($arrayImage);// I shuffle the array
    $_SESSION['arrayImage'] = $arrayImage;//save array to the session
}
?>
```

and in the php pages i have this code between the style tags:

```
<style type="text/css">
<?php 
if($picture < 15){//if I'm not out fo bound I continue
    echo 'body {background-image:url("images/bg'.$arrayImage[$picture].'hq.jpg");}';
}
else{// else I set picture to default value and restar the loop.
    $picture = 0;
    $_SESSION['picture'] = $picture;// save it
    echo 'body {background-image:url("images/bg'.$arrayImage[$picture].'hq.jpg");}';
}       
?>      
</style>
```

The problem is that the images are not showed immediately but I have to zoom the pages then they appear.

Comment: Hi Martin, please redact your name and workplace from [so] Questions and Answers. I might come in for a coffee seeing I live down the road **but** we don't advertise here at [so] - if we do it has to have a disclaimer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've checked the output and it's correct.
If that's the case, try removing quotes from around the background url:

```
body {background-image:url("images/bg'.$arrayImage[$picture].'hq.jpg");}
```

to

```
body {background-image:url(images/bg'.$arrayImage[$picture].'hq.jpg);}
```

By the way it's absolutely valid to use them, but it's quite rare, and iOS's Webkit renderer sometimes likes to produce some very buggy results even with valid markup. Unfortunately it's different than Android's Webkit renderer or any x86 Webkit engine, so these problems are not reproducable and inspectable deeply without a very expensive Apple device.

CSS modifications done with JS, specially with frameworks (for example jQuery) are often parsed intelligently resulting in syntax corrections when needed, so that's why those quotation marks are the primary suspects for me.